# Firebase analytics how to get events stored data of users?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics

I am trying to get the records of the events stored from the application side to **Firebase Analytics** using **Laravel** or **PHP**.
No data is showing in the Console but, approximately every 30 seconds, an event occurs.

Is **Firebase Analytics** a storage facility? Are **Firebase Analytics** and **Firebase Database** the same?

I've tried using the `kreait/firebase-php` library but did I cannot get data of events that stored at **Firebase Analytics**.

Answer (score 4):

Google Analytics for Firebase events are not directly accessible from the client-side (mobile app or from a web page).

However, you can access them via BigQuery from PHP.

Here are some hopefully helpful links: cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api

To answer your other questions above, Firebase Analytics is not a storage solution, it is an analytics solution; Firebase Analytics is not the same as Firebase Database, and Firebase Analytics does not use Firebase Database to store its data.

Comment: Actually i wanted to get all those  events of users using php or laravel.
is it possible???

Comment: Is there another way or any plugin for that to access those analytics record.
if there is not possibility then fire base analytics is useless.

Comment: As stated above you can access your Firebase Analytics data through the Firebase console or through BigQuery.  Firebase Analytics internal data is not designed to be accessed directly by the app.  To answer your other questions above, Firebase Analytics is not a storage solution, it is an analytics solution; Firebase Analytics is not the same as Firebase Database, and Firebase Analytics does not use Firebase Database to store its data.

Comment: You had asked for BigQuery. Is there a option to get firebase analytics data activities from BigQuery using any of sever side language? php or laravel..

Comment: Yes.  My original answer was incorrect/misleading about PHP.  Sorry!  I've edited it.  
Getting into the details goes beyond my expertise.  Here are some hopefully helpful links: 
https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api

Comment: Comments are not part of an answer and can be removed at any time. If there is relevant information needed in the answer, put it there.